# Integrate using Beta function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have an integral $$ \int _0 ^1 \frac{(1-u)^{1/3}}{(1+u)u^{1/3}} du$$ which should be calculated using a substitution that converts it to beta function but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \begin{eqnarray}
I&=&\int _0 ^1 \frac{(1-u)^{1/3}}{(1+u)u^{1/3}} du\overset{u=\frac{1}{1+t}}=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^{1/3}}{(t+1)(t+2)} dt\\
&\overset{x=t^{1/3}}=&3\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^3}{(x^3+1)(x^3+2)}dx\\
&=&6\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^3+2}dx-3\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^3+1}dx.
\end{eqnarray}$$
Now using
$$ \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^3+a^3}dx=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt3a^2}$$
it is easy to get
$$ I=\frac{2(\sqrt[3]2-1)\pi}{\sqrt3}. $$